# how do i make text (using drawString) appear on JFrame with a button click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have this project wherein I have one button, and when I click it, a shape moves by 10 pixels (it's juice being sipped from a glass). On certain intervals of clicks (5th click, 10th click etc), I want to display some text onto the JFrame using the drawString method (similar to how when comic book characters punch someone, a giant POW appears on screen. So far, I've instantiated the code so that it prints (using System.out.println) the word onto the console. How do I make it so that instead of printing onto the console, the word (as a drawString) appears on the frame instead?

class DrawingFrame:

```
class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            JButton click = (JButton) ae.getSource(); 
            
            if (click==sipButton) //one click on sipButton = juice gets sipped and glass slowly empties 
            {
                clickCounter = clickCounter+1;
                if (clickCounter==5) //on the 5th click (the 5th sip), an expression flashes on screen
                {
                    System.out.println("NICE"); //this works. now turn the console output into a drawString
                }
                else if (clickCounter==10)
                {
                    System.out.println("WOW");
                }
                //...
            
                dc.nextScene(); //dc = drawing component
            }
            dc.repaint();
        }
```

class DrawingComponent:

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform reset = g2d.getTransform();
   
        //...
        //other shapes

        glass.draw(g2d,reset);
        juice.draw(g2d, reset);
        straw.draw(g2d,reset);
    }

    public void nextScene()
    {
        juice.setScene(); //calls for a method in class juice that contains the code for the juice diminishing per click/sip
    }
    
    //here is where i'm unsure. i don't know if this is right
    //my idea is to call this method in the DrawingFrame class and place it where "System.out.println("NICE") is right now, but i don't know
    public void shouldBeWord(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform reset = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.drawString("NICE", 300, 300);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: The text you want to paint should be a property of your class. Then add the painting code to your paintComponent() method. That is the text is just a property like your glass/juice/straw objects. Whenever the text changes you invoke repaint() on your component.

Comment: @camickr ohhhh so i treat it as a class of it's own containing the same methods as the other objects...didn't think of that. thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a class of its own. Its just that the painting logic needs to be done in the paintComponent(...) method. Think of a JLabel. It has properties like setText(), setIcon(), setBorder(), setBackground(). So in your case you have some defined objects, like glass/juice/straw that you paint. But the text could just be a property of the panel. You can then use the setForeground() method of the panel to control the color of the text.

Comment: @camickr i've created and initialized the code for the words on the JComponent, i placed the final ".draw()" part of the code in the paintComponent, 
however the text appears on screen immediately instead of by click. how would i reference this in the JFrame class so that I can place it in the proper "if (clicks==n)" statement?

Comment: @camickr is it right to do this? 

in paintComponent: 
`protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    word1.paint(g2d,reset);
}` 

in paintFrame: 
`class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
        JButton click = (JButton) ae.getSource(); 
        if (click==sipButton) {
            clickCounter = clickCounter+1; 
            if (clickCounter==5) {
                //this is where i want the word to go
            }`

Comment: When you add a property to a class you need a method to change the property. So you need a method like `setText(...)` to change the text as required.